# Why was 'strabismus' chosen to mean 'any misalignment of the eyes'?

Tags: terminology

The [AAO](https://www.aao.org/eye-health/diseases/what-is-strabismus) and [AAPOS](https://www.aapos.org/terms/conditions/100) don't associate strabismus with squinting. So why was [a word etymologically meaning 'squinting'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/strabismus) adopted to describe  this muscle condition?

> "a squinting," 1680s, medical Latin,
>   from Greek strabismos,
>   from strabizein "to squint,"
>   from strabos "squinting, squint-eyed," related to strobos "a whirling round,"
>   from PIE root [*streb(h)-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*streb(h)-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "to wind, turn." Earlier in Englished form strabism (1650s).

Comment: This might be better for english.SE or something

Answer (score 2):

The word "squint" has [multiple meanings](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/squint?s=t)-- the ophthalmic definition being:

> A condition of the eye consisting in noncoincidence of
>   the optic axes; strabismus.

"Strabismus" does mean "squint", but squint doesn't necessarily mean "to look at something with your eyes partially closed".

In fact, in [one of the historical examples on dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/asquint), the related word "asquint" is used in the following sentence from the 17th century:

> But I know that Providence looketh not asquint, but looketh straight
>   out, and through all men's darkness.

This usage seems to imply that strabismus (or at least not looking "straight out") has a long association with the word squint.

Comment: I wonder if the original greek meaning of strabos applied to the non-parallel gaze.